# R SVM predict function returning nothing

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, predict

I'm trying to use a SVM for a regression problem in R. I'm trying to predict a probability, NB, based off of 5 factors, R498, P499, T500, Y501, and H505. The model seems to be built on my training dataset without issue, but calling predict on my test dataset using the same model returns nothing. I cannot share my data as it is confidential, but I can tell you that the five factors are correctly initialized and the response is correctly considered to be of type double. There is no missing data in the csv I am loading.

```
library(caret)
index <- createDataPartition(mydata$NB, p = .70, list = FALSE)
train <- mydata[index,]
test <- mydata[-index,]
library(nnet)
model <- svm(NB ~ R498 + P499 + T500 + Y501 + H505, data = train, kernel="linear")
summary(model)
```

`Call:svm(formula = NB ~ R498 + P499 + T500 + Y501 + H505, data = train, kernel = "linear") Parameters:SVM-Type:  eps-regressionSVM-Kernel:  linearcost:  1gamma:  0.01041667 epsilon:  0.1 Number of Support Vectors:  3185`

```
predict(model, newdata=test)

# output:
> named numeric(0)
```